# what is v and x means in freeRTOS task creating or used in it?

Tags: rtos, freertos

what does mean x and v in task creating or managing of free RTOS?
xTaskcreate or vTaskcreate?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The leading character(s) of the FreeRTOS functions identify the return type of the function.  Functions that start with "v" return void.  Functions that start with "x" typically return a result code or handle.  See the [Naming Conventions](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Coding-Standard-and-Style-Guide.html#NamingConventions) page of the FreeRTOS coding standard.

Answer (score 5):

Acording to FreeRTOS [Documentation](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Coding-Standard-and-Style-Guide.html#NamingConventions):

> - Variables of non stdint types are prefixed **x**. Examples
>     include  *BaseType_t* and *TickType_t*, which are portable layer
>     defined *typedefs* for the natural or most efficient type for the
>     architecture and the type used to hold the RTOS tick count
>     respectively.
> - Variables of type *size_t* are also prefixed **x**.
> - API functions are prefixed with their **return type**, as per the
>     convention defined for variables, with the addition of the prefix
>     **v** for **void**.

In addition, the second part of the variable/function name, for
   example Task, indicates the file in which the variable/function
   implemented, i.e. task.c.