# FreeRTOS Hungarian Notation

Tags: c, embedded, freertos, hungarian-notation

I'm a complete newbie in RTOS and C programming, and I'm still getting used to the C good practices yet. So I opened a project which uses FreeRTOS, and I notice that the OS files use the Hungarian Notation. I know the notation a little, but faced some new "standards" in the `FreeRTOS.h` file, which are:

```
#ifndef configASSERT
    #define configASSERT( x )
    #define configASSERT_DEFINED 0
#else
    #define configASSERT_DEFINED 1
#endif
```

And below that,

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_xTaskGetSchedulerState
    #define INCLUDE_xTaskGetSchedulerState 0
#endif

#ifndef INCLUDE_xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle
    #define INCLUDE_xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle 0
#endif
```

I've seen this **x** - as in ***x***TaskGetCurrentTaskHandle - everywhere. Also, **v**, **pd** and variable names like that, like in line `728` of the header in question:

```
#if configENABLE_BACKWARD_COMPATIBILITY == 1
    #define eTaskStateGet eTaskGetState
    #define portTickType TickType_t
    #define xTaskHandle TaskHandle_t
    #define xQueueHandle QueueHandle_t
    #define xSemaphoreHandle SemaphoreHandle_t
    #define xQueueSetHandle QueueSetHandle_t
    #define xQueueSetMemberHandle QueueSetMemberHandle_t
    #define xTimeOutType TimeOut_t
    #define xMemoryRegion MemoryRegion_t
    #define xTaskParameters TaskParameters_t
    #define xTaskStatusType TaskStatus_t
    #define xTimerHandle TimerHandle_t
    #define xCoRoutineHandle CoRoutineHandle_t
    #define pdTASK_HOOK_CODE TaskHookFunction_t
    #define portTICK_RATE_MS portTICK_PERIOD_MS

    /* Backward compatibility within the scheduler code only - these definitions
    are not really required but are included for completeness. */
    #define tmrTIMER_CALLBACK TimerCallbackFunction_t
    #define pdTASK_CODE TaskFunction_t
    #define xListItem ListItem_t
    #define xList List_t
```

I've searched everywhere what would those "initials" stand for, but still could not figure that out.

So, if anyone could help me to understand this, or could show me a path or something, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199690/what-is-v-and-x-means-in-freertos-task-creating-or-used-in-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199690/what-is-v-and-x-means-in-freertos-task-creating-or-used-in-it)

Comment: Please note that Hungarian notation isn't necessarily considered as good practice. It isn't used much nowadays. See the disadvantages listed on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Comment: @Lundin, thanks for the comment. Actually, I think this project I'm working on is kinda old, and the previous programmers used Hungarian notation in all of it. Once it's a complete environment of an embedded system, I think I'll have no way to get out of it... I'll have to get kinda used to that, lol. Thanks for the link, I'll surely take a look!

Comment: The style guide and coding standard is <a href="http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Coding-Standard-and-Style-Guide.html">described on the FreeRTOS.org website</a>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [the man](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Coding-Standard-and-Style-Guide.html#NamingConventions)

> **Naming Conventions**
>
> The RTOS kernel and demo application source code use the following conventions:
>
> **Variables**
>
> - Variables of type `uint32_t` are prefixed **ul**, where the **'u'** denotes `unsigned` and the **'l'** denotes `long`.
> - Variables of type `uint16_t` are prefixed **us**, where the **'u'** denotes 'unsigned' and the 's' denotes `short`.
> - Variables of type `uint8_t` are prefixed **uc**, where the **'u'** denotes 'unsigned' and the 'c' denotes `char`.
> - ***Variables of non stdint types are prefixed x***. Examples include    `BaseType_t` and `TickType_t`, which are portable layer defined typedefs for the natural or most efficient type for the architecture and the type used to hold the RTOS tick count respectively.
> - `Unsigned` variables of non stdint types have an additional prefix **u**. For example variables of type `UBaseType_t` (`unsigned BaseType_t`) are prefixed **ux**.
> - Variables of type `size_t` are also prefixed **x**.
> - Enumerated variables are prefixed **e**
> - Pointers have an additional prefixed **p**, for example a pointer to a `uint16_t` will have prefix **pus**.
> - In line with MISRA guides, unqualified standard char types are only permitted to hold `ASCII characters` and are prefixed **c**.
> - In line with MISRA guides, variables of type `char *` are only permitted to hold pointers to `ASCII strings` and are prefixed **pc**.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

> **Functions**
>
> - File scope static (private) functions are prefixed with prv.
> - API functions are prefixed with their return type, as per the convention defined for variables, with the addition of the prefix **v** for `void`.
> - API function names start with the name of the file in which they are defined. For example `vTaskDelete` is defined in tasks.c, and has a `void` return type.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

> **Macros**
>
> - Macros are pre-fixed with the file in which they are defined. **The pre-fix is lower case**. For example, `configUSE_PREEMPTION` is defined in FreeRTOSConfig.h.
> - **Other than the pre-fix, macros are written in all upper case**, and use an underscore to separate words.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Comment: @LP's, thank you so much man, I'm still getting used to all this environment of embedded systems. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I just discovered it and have now referenced it [in my answer describing Hungarian Notation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50091884/4561887). It appears FreeRTOS uses primarily **Systems Hungarian** notation with a little bit of **Apps Hungarian** style notation.